# Interesting observation about matrices generated by "simple" functions of indices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I made an intriguing observation about matrices generated by "simple" functions of the indices, like polynomials. Namely, it seems that given a polynomial $P(i, j)$, then the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ given by $a_{ij} = P(i, j)$ is singular for a sufficiently large size. This, despite singular matrices being in a sense "rare". Why is this? Is this a known result with a known proof?

It also seems to work even with other kinds of "simple" functions, e.g. if $a_{ij} = \sin(i + j)$, the same seems to hold.

And if the conjecture as stated as above is not true, then it surely seems like something along the lines of "the chances of getting a non-singular matrix off a 'random' polynomial/'simple' function of the indices falls off *rapidly* with increasing matrix size". Is it?

Comment: Matrix $a_{ij} = i^j$ is not singular. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix
And I think that $i^j$ is fairly simple function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any fixed $j$, the entries in the $j$th column are consecutive values of the polynomial $P(i,j)$ (considered as a polynomial of $i$ alone). It is known that the [$n$th forward difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#n-th_difference) of a polynomial equals $0$ when $n$ is greater than the degree of the polynomial. In other words, there is a linear relation among those values of the polynomial, with the coefficients independent of the actual polynomial (just depending on the degree). In other other words, there is a fixed linear relation among the rows of the matrix (when the number of rows exceeds the degree of $P(i,j)$ as a polynomial in $i$); and that linear relation forces the matrix to be singular.

The other example can be seen to be singular by noting that $\sin(i+j) = \sin i \cos j + \cos i \sin j$; therefore $A$ is the sum of the two rank-1 matrices $(\sin i \cos j)$ and $(\cos i \sin j)$, hence has rank at most $1+1=2$, hence is singular if $3\times3$ or larger.